# flink how to convert the result of JDBCInputFormat to DataSet of Tuple type

Tags: apache-flink

I am having following code to get data from jdbc:

```
DataSet dbData =
                env.createInput(
                        JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
                                .setDrivername(bdpService.getDriver(dataSource))
                                .setDBUrl(dbUrl)
                                .setQuery(sql)
                                .setUsername(dataSource.getUsername())
                                .setPassword(dataSource.getPassword())
                                .setRowTypeInfo(new RowTypeInfo(getTypes(transInfo)))
                                .finish(), getTypes(transInfo));
```

then i would like to take Tuple type operation on the dataset, like groupBy, etc.
but it is of type Row, how can I convert it, or any other ways to achive this get data from jdbc into the DataSet type?

thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as following:

```
public static class RowToTupleMapper implements ResultTypeQueryable, MapFunction<Row, Tuple>{
    private Class tupleClass;
    private TypeInformation[] typeInformations;

    public RowToTupleMapper(Class tupleClass, TypeInformation[] typeInformations){
        this.tupleClass = tupleClass;
        this.typeInformations = typeInformations;
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple map(Row value) throws Exception {
        Tuple tuple = (Tuple)tupleClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < value.getArity(); i++) {
            Object obj = value.getField(i);
            tuple.setField(obj, i);
        }
        return tuple;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation getProducedType() {
        return new TupleTypeInfo(typeInformations);
    }
}
```

using this helper class like this:

```
final String tupleClassName = "org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple" + transInfo.getSelects().size();
final Class tupleClass = Class.forName(tupleClassName);
DataSet<Tuple> ret = dbData.map(new RowToTupleMapper(tupleClass, typeInformations));
```